# How to verify UPI address is valid or not? Is there any free APIs? I want to check if the entered UPI address is existing or not

Tags: verification, razorpay, upi

Verification of UPI address using API.

I tried razorpay with this API: "https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/validate/vpa" but got response as:

> {"error":{"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"The requested URL was not found on the server.","source":"NA","step":"NA","reason":"NA","metadata":{}}}

I've passed client key and secret correctly but still receives this error.

Comment: The error says the  URL which you are hitting is not found on server hence a BAD REQUEST, can you re-check with documentation for the API contract ? Can you check if you are doing it correctly ? https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/upi/vpa-validation/

Comment: Yes, I tried with postman with the correct api provided in the documentation.